# How to use Array in JEXL?

Tags: arrays, jexl

Using [JEXL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html), I am trying to initialize array and than adding elements into it, however below code gives me **'unsolvable property '0'** error.

```
var abc=[]; 
abc[0]=5;
```

1) How can I initialize empty array and keep adding values in it?

2) Can I use it like List, where I do not need to specify size at the time of initialization ?

Answer (score 0):

in [JEXL syntax](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) you can initialize objects with `new` function.

Other option is to add to context arraylist:

This is a working example with jexl2:

```
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    String jexlExp = "var abc=new(\"java.util.ArrayList\", 1);abc[0]=5";
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression( jexlExp );
    List<Integer> abc = new ArrayList<>(1);
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
    //jc.set("abc", abc ); second option to add arraylist to context
    Object o = e.evaluate(jc);
```

Comment: Is there any shorter/simpler way like 'var abc=[];' ?

Comment: But I do want to initialize array inside my script, not from outside.

Comment: @Pratik look carefully, I commented the initialize from outside

Comment: Thanks, I think it's not working in JEXL3 however. we need abc.add(5) instead of abc[0]=5; Anyways, do you know any simpler way to instantiate empty array in JEXL ? I mean something like var array=[]; ?

Answer (score 0):

In JEXL, the syntax `[]` creates a Java array, not a `List`.  As an array, it has a fixed size, so you cannot add values to it.  However, JEXL 3.2 has a new syntax for creating an ArrayList literal.  Basically, you add `...` as the final element.

So in JEXL 3.2, your example could be written as:

```
var abc=[...]; 
abc.add(5);
```

See the [JEXL literal syntax reference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html#Literals) for more information.